# What is the benefit of embedding pg_advisory_lock inside SELECT vs explicitly using another statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I cannot really understand the example from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html

where they embed the lock along with the SELECT clause 
`SELECT pg_advisory_lock(id) FROM foo WHERE id = 12345; -- ok`

What is it selecting from `FOO`? I would understand better if it is like

```
SELECT pg_advisory_lock(123); //lock
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = 12345;
```

where it is explicitly locking the block. I can't seem to find explanation on how to really use advisory lock anywhere that explains the differnece between both Embedding and Explicitly on its own statement.

Answer (score 8):

Doing `SELECT pg_advisory_lock(123);` will create a lock on `123`, whether it is a valid value or not. Doing `SELECT pg_advisory_lock(id) FROM foo WHERE id = 123;` will create the lock only if there is an entry for ID 123 in table foo.

Let's note the line found in the [pg_locks doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-locks.html):

> The actual meaning of the keys is up to the user

which tends to imply that the select/from/where syntax is for *associating* the lock to an existing row, while the lone select syntax is for a broader meaning, like an application-wide lock.